# Detect the outermost corners of a floor-plan image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on getting the outermost traces of floor plans using corner detection. I have used Harris Corner Detection by OpenCV to detect the corners of a floor plan image. The detected corners are shown in the image below. How can I obtain the coordinates of the outermost corners detected and join them with lines using OpenCV for Python?

[FLoorPlan Image with corners detected in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3S7j.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Note: your images are missing. You need to upload to some free hosting service and put the URLs in your post.

Comment: Are you trying to get the Convex Hull ?  Check opencv documentation : https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull

Comment: No i am not trying to get the convex hull. I just want the outline of the external bearing walls. I have tried to achieve this using a convex hull but it did not work well